# HTML5 Article LIst

Tags: html

I have coded a HTML5 list of articles. I have been searching if this is the correct way to use the new HTML5 semantic tags, but I am still unsure. Is this markup correct in terms of using semantics?

```
<section>
   <article>
      <h2>Article</h2>
      <p>Description of article</p>
   </article>
   <article>
      <h2>Article</h2>
      <p>Description of article</p>
   </article>
   <article>
      <h2>Article</h2>
      <p>Description of article</p>
   </article>
</section>
```

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183132/how-to-correctly-use-section-tag-in-html5

Comment: Better candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that's fine, although it would be better if the `<section>` also had a heading, e.g.

```
<section>
   <h1>Article List</h1>
   <article>
      <h2>Article</h2>
      <p>Description of article</p>
   </article>
   ...
</section>
```