# Create elements with jQuery each not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a dynamic rotator that I am trying to create a nav button for each image. I dont have access to the back end so I have to do this with jQuery on load.

My thinking is that I find each LI item and create a new  and append it in the nav but I cant seem to get it working

http://jsfiddle.net/bc0yu7pg/2/

**jQuery**

```
navItem = 0;

$( "li" ).each(function() {
    navLink = '<a href="javascript:void() id="rot' + navItem + '"></a>';
    $('section').append(navLink);
    navItem++;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
        <ul>
            <li>Slide</li>
            <li>Slide</li>
            <li>Slide</li>
        </ul>
        <nav></nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Make sure you close the href in your a tag.  It could also use some anchor text.  Also, wrap it in a doc ready to ensure it fires after the li's are added to the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('section nav')` instead of `$('section').` Try this:

```
navItem = 0;

$( "li" ).each(function() {
    navLink = '<a href="javascript:void()" id="rot' + navItem + '"></a>';
    $('section nav').append(navLink);
    navItem++;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/bc0yu7pg/7/)**

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing quote mark.  You never close the href quote.  Also you should assign to the nav as @Unknown said.

```
navItem = 0;

$( "li" ).each(function() {
    navLink = '<a href="javascript:void()" id="rot' + navItem + '"></a>';
    $('section nav').append(navLink);
    navItem++;
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/qd4d993p/)

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your link to the `<section>` element rather than to the `<nav>` element.

```
$( "li" ).each(function() {
    navLink = '<a href="javascript:void() id="rot' + navItem + '"></a>';
    $('nav').append(navLink);
    navItem++;
});
```

See this updated jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/bc0yu7pg/5/

However I think your CSS may need some extra work.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use section as a normal container in DOM for this kind of manipulation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183188/1027550