# Is the element <header> or <section> mechanically different than <div>?

Tags: css, html

I just learned HTML and CSS a few days ago, and now I'm starting to get into HTML5, and learning about the new elements, such as `<header>` and `<section>`, it sounds to me like they're used to make your code easier to read and clarify which is which when viewing the code, but mechanically speaking it sounds like they do the same thing as a `<div>` would do, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: They're all block level if that's what you mean. Obviously different semantically though.

Comment: Next time do some research before asking a question. There are plenty of articles through a basic Google search. And a search on this site. Try to post questions that address a specific technical problem that you are encountering and add details.

Answer (score 1):

A `<div>` is a generic block level container that you use to group elements. You can use `<div>`s anywhere.

see [How to correctly use "section" tag in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183132/how-to-correctly-use-section-tag-in-html5) for more info on the `<section>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanically speaking   and  are the same ;) Just block tags.

Although logically/programmably they have different functions, and are created for different purpose.